# Run parallel tasks for multiple files in directory on mounted volume in Airflow DAG

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, airflow, pipeline

I have Airflow deployed on kubernetes in some namespace on my work server and a few mounted volumes to this namespace.

I need to process each file in specific directory on mounted volume in parallel, but only in 3 threads (same tasks in parallel) due to limited resources. Each task is a `KubernetesPodOperator`. The main problem is i don't understand how to pass filenames to `KubernetesPodOperator` correctly. Inside `KubernetesPodOperator` paths on mounted volume are available due to `volume_mounts` and `volumes` parameters. But, if I use the first available file from the list of files in the directory from within the `KubernetesPodOperator`, it may cause the same file to be processed by multiple `KubernetesPodOperator` and result in an error. On the other hand mounted volumes aren't visible from DAG, therefore I cannot pass the appropriate filenames to `KubernetesPodOperator` directly from the DAG.

Example of `KubernetesPodOperator`:

```
fasterq_dump_instance_1 = KubernetesPodOperator(
        name="fasterq_dump_instance_1",
        task_id="fasterq_dump_instance_1",
        namespace="namespace-name",
        in_cluster=True,
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        get_logs=True,
        image="imagename",
        image_pull_policy="IfNotPresent",
        resources=k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(
            limits={"cpu": "2", "memory": "10Gi"},
            requests={"cpu": "1", "memory": "1Gi"},
        ),

        cmds=["python", "fasterq_dump.py", filename_to_process],

        volume_mounts=[
            V1VolumeMount(mount_path="/uftp", name="uftp-namespace"),
        ],
        volumes=[
            V1Volume(
                name="uftp-namespace",
                persistent_volume_claim=V1PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource(
                    claim_name="uftp-namespace"
                )
            ),
        ],
    )
```

The main goal is develop DAG looks like this:

[image]

Each task (`KubernetesPodOperator`) should process one sample (file in mounted volume) and trigger start downstream tasks. And when task finished process some file it should immediately start process next available file in corresponding to this task directory on mounted volume.

For example i have 4 files in directory for `fasterq_dump` task after `download_sra` task:

```
f1.sra
f2.sra
f3.sra
f4.sra
```

First three `fasterq_dump` start processing the first three files (it can be in random order). So first instance of `fasterq_dump` processing `f1.sra`, second -- `f2.sra`, third -- `f3.sra`. At some time point one of these instances is completed, for example `fasterq_dump_instance_2`. It means that `f2.sra` has already been removed, `f1.sra`, `f3.sra` is still being processed by other instances and `f4.sra` is available to process. So the free `fasterq_dump_instance_2` should process this file.

How can I implement the pipeline described above?

Comment: do you have a different volume for each file or one volume for the 3 files?

Comment: One volume for all files for one DAG

Comment: You might be able to process the first available file but then your had to be sure that only ome of your fasterq_dump processes looks for the first file at the same time. Create some lock file which contains information about the fasterq_dump instance, move the first file to a local directory in your pod, release the lock and process the local file. Other instances had to wait until the lock is removed.